# Bulk api query batch size limit is 10,000 records

Tags: bulk-api

When running **bulk api query, batch size limit is 10,000 records** (from documentation: A batch can contain a maximum of 10,000 records.)
What can I do if my query result is bigger than 10000, how can I retrive the rest of the data?

I saw that the rest API returns nextRecordsUrl. Maybe I'm looking for something like that but in Bulk api.

Answer (score 12):

The batch size thats specified in the document is for a single batch.You can process as many batches as you like limiting to 2000 per 24 hour rolling period.

10k is the maximum batch size that you can set per batch.So say you have 50K records then 5 batches will be the minimum no of batches required .

Bulk API can process any no of records .**Only limit you may have to look is no of batches per day.This limit is 2000 batches per 24 hour .(On rolling basis)**

Comment: Hey @Mohith, you have mentioned as limit on no of batches in a day is 2000.Is it for overall org or is it only for one batch class.

Answer (score 1):

If you have PK chunking enabled for the query then the batch size can be from  the chunk size 100,000, and the maximum size is 250,000

Refer this link for more information

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/async_api_headers_enable_pk_chunking.htm

Answer (score 0):

Bulk API Query batch limit is not 10,000. It is 1GB per file and you can retrieve 15 such files.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my case I cannot determine the total number of records?So at such times how can I determine the batch numbers.Moreover how can I write the Query for this case

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Your post is not really an answer, but more of a comment. May I suggest that you take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help) to help you get the most out of the site?