# Bulk API V1 Query showing a batch size of only 1 for 144717 records. Why?

Tags: bulk-api

From Salesforce documentation and questions such as [Bulk api query batch size limit is 10,000 records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9160/bulk-api-query-batch-size-limit-is-10-000-records), it appears that the batch size limit is 10,000 records for V1 bulk API.

Also listed here: https://sf.watch/articles/147/salesforce-bulk-api-v1-vs-salesforce-bulk-api-v2-a-general-guide/

Using data loader I see the following for 144717 records:

[image]

Why is it only showing 1 batch and not 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For queries, the [documentation actually says that v1 will only return one batch unless PK chunking is enabled.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_bulkapi.htm)

> Without PK chunking enabled, only one batch is created. If you create a batch with PK chunking enabled, batches are broken up based on the number of records in the chunk. This can range from 100,000 to 250,000 records.